# Postgres view to count unique columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I have a table of entries that I want to create a Postgres view for. The table called `opens`, records the number of times individual posts have been opened. The same reader could open the same post multiple times.

I'd like the Postgres view to return the total number of times posts have been opened, but also the amount of unique opens that were by the same reader, for the week. So a post could have been opened 7 times this week, but only by 2 readers.

Thus total opens VS unique opens for the week.

The `opens` table looks something like;

```
id uuid 
inserted_at timestamp
post_id uuid references posts
reader_id uuid references readers
```

The view should return a list of entries showing the number of unique entries created for posts by `post_id`, their `weekly_opens` and `unique_weeks_opens` respectively, for the week.

So if the first post was opened 7 times in total by 2 readers, and the second post opened 10 times by 7 readers, the view should return something like;

```
| post_id | weekly_opens | unique_weeks_opens |
|---------|--------------|--------------------|
| abc-def |.     7.      |.       2.          |
| ghi-jkl |.     10.     |.       7.          |
```

My current unsuccessful attempt looks like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    opens.post_id,
    COUNT (opens.post_id) AS weekly_opens,
    COUNT (opens.reader_id) AS unique_weeks_opens
FROM opens
WHERE
    opens.inserted_at >= date_trunc('week',current_date)
GROUP BY
    opens.post_id
```

I have very little experience with databases, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how a week is defined here? Is it like post is opened in last 7 days from the current date or something else?

Comment: better to provide sample data. You can use DISTINCT keyword inside count() for readerId.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close! Move your DISTINCT into your COUNT (see below), and that should do the trick.

```
SELECT
    opens.post_id,
    COUNT (opens.post_id) AS weekly_opens,
    COUNT (DISTINCT opens.reader_id) AS unique_weeks_opens
FROM opens
WHERE
    opens.inserted_at >= date_trunc('week',current_date)
GROUP BY
    opens.post_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. you've used my tricks...